# Smoke simulation only rendering when I apply smoke modifier

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation

I was able to render the scene without applying the modifier before but after some fiddling with the smoke material, some weight paints in the scene, and rebaking, the smoke stopped appearing on the final render. It only appears again on the final rendered image after I hit apply to the smoke modifier. The problem is when I apply the smoke modifier, the smoke becomes more intense and seems to take the shape of its domain.

Update: Okay, it seems like the smoke will render and stay intact if I just apply the flow object modifier but I would still like to know why it stopped rendering before I apply the modifier

These are my domain settings
[image: My domain settings] 
[image: My high resolution seetings]

My domain material settings
[image: My domain material settings]

Answer (score 0):

The reason what is think is your density for smoke in principled volume shader is very low you have set it to "0.100"  try increasing it to 1.00 or even more.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. It just happened that it started to render again even without applying the smoke modifier. I duplicated the flow object and disabled the duplicate, applied the smoke object but for some reason, it wasn't showing on the render again. Then I brought back the duplicate, disabled the original flow object and it started to render again even without changing the density or applying the smoke modifier.